# Cognos reports showing no data from url

Tags: reporting, reportviewer, cognos

I can run all my reports from report studio just fine. So its not a question of query or data or even report specs.

When i call them from URL i am getting no data in the report. There obviously should be data.

We had **just upgraded from 8.2 to 8.3** and it is not all the reports... only a select few.

This is serious problem since our users can no longer run these reports.

please help.

-k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was worked around by recreating the reports from scratch in 8.3 by copying over all the contents using the clipboard and saving it over the old one.   There must be something wrong with our reports and the cognos upgrade engine.

This fixes 90% of our reports. we still have some that do not behave correctly.